# sexmachine reporting None for all lines

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use sexmachine to identify the genders of names in a pandas DataFrame using the below code:

```
def gender(n):
    d.get_gender(n)
df['gender'] = df['first_name'].apply(gender);
```

But every row is "None."

Thanks for any help

Comment: Now I'm disappointed there's no tag `sexmachine`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return the value

Try this:

```
def gender(n):
    return d.get_gender(n)

df['gender'] = df['first_name'].apply(gender);
```